# Select max of nested id from amazon redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

My database is an amazon redshift.

I have a table that looks like this -

| id | nested_id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | '2021-01-01' | 5 |
| 1 | 20 | '2021-01-01' | 10 |
| 1 | 10 | '2021-01-02' | 6 |
| 1 | 20 | '2021-01-02' | 11 |
| 1 | 10 | '2021-01-03' | 7 |
| 1 | 20 | '2021-01-03' | 12 |
| 2 | 30 | '2021-01-01' | 5 |
| 2 | 40 | '2021-01-01' | 10 |
| 2 | 30 | '2021-01-02' | 6 |
| 2 | 40 | '2021-01-02' | 11 |
| 2 | 30 | '2021-01-03' | 7 |
| 2 | 40 | '2021-01-03' | 12 |

So this is basically a table that tracks values by id over time, except for every id there can be a nested_id. And the dates and values are primarily connected to the nested_id.

However, let's say I'm starting with the `id` field, but for each `id` I want to only return the points over time for the `nested_id` that has the greater sum of points.

So right now I'm just grabbing it like this...

```
select *
from mytable
where id in (1, 2)
```

except I only want it to return `nested_id` rows where the maximum `value` of that nested_id is the greatest.

So here's how I would do this manually.

For `id` of 1, the maximum value is 12, and the `nested_id` of that value is `20`
For `id` of 2, the maximum value is 12, and the `nested_id` of that value is `40`

So my return table should be

| id | nested_id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | '2021-01-01' | 10 |
| 1 | 20 | '2021-01-02' | 11 |
| 1 | 20 | '2021-01-03' | 12 |
| 2 | 40 | '2021-01-01' | 10 |
| 2 | 40 | '2021-01-02' | 11 |
| 2 | 40 | '2021-01-03' | 12 |

Is there an easy way of performing this query? I'm assuming you have to partition somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with `row_number` [window functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html)

```sql
with maxs as (
    select id, 
           nested_id, 
           value, 
           row_number() over (partition by id order by value desc) rn
    from mytable
)
select mt.*
from mytable mt
    left join maxs on mt.id = maxs.id and mt.nested_id = maxs.nested_id
where maxs.rn = 1
```